# Best way to extract a subset of path objects from an SVG file by property

Tags: xml, svg

So I'm writing a utility to extract the parts of an SVG file that can be vectorised on a laser cutter vs the parts that need to be rasterised. To start with, for the vector parts, I'm interested in just the  paths.

I could this by writing a general XML parser, extracting all the properties, chaining any transforms, clips etc. from the hierarchy of groups along the way and directing the output to 2 files (one with just what I need to render the vector side, one with everything just these lines removed).

This does, however, seem a little like a sledgehammer to crack a nut - so is there some query-based method or technique to pull out the lines I need without implementing a full-on parser myself ?

Comment: _query-based method_ - xpath?

Comment: Why write an xml parser, there are plenty of existing parsers you could use.

Comment: @Robert Lognson: Well, I meant use a parser and write the handler code - not actually implement the XML parsing, just the callback routines for element-start etc. :) ... Alexander Petrov: Thanks - I knew there'd be something. I'll go read up on it :)